# what is $x$ for $\tan^23x = 2\sin^23x$

Tags: trigonometry

If $x$ = acute angle then find $x$ such that $\tan^23x = 2\sin^23x$.

So 
$\tan3x = \sqrt2\sin3x$

$\frac{1}{\cos3x} = \sqrt2$

$3x = 45^{\circ}$

what are all the possibilies for $x$ ?
because the question asked for all possibilities of $x$

The options are: $180, 195, 120, 135, 360$

Comment: In what way are you told that your answer is wrong?  $x=15^{\circ}$ looks like a valid solution.  But the more important part is, is that the only solution?

Comment: Why not simplify everything from the beginning and let $y = 3 x$?

Comment: Hint: What if $\sin3x=0$?

Comment: The only issues I see is that $tan3x = *\pm* \sqrt 2 sin3x$ and $sinx = 0$ is ignored. Perhaps the questioner wants a general solution ($n\pi \pm \frac \pi 4$, where $n$ is an int)

Comment: The problem wants $x\in(0^{\circ},90^{\circ})$.

Comment: Ah, just saw that the sum is asked. I guess the possibility of $tan3x = -\sqrt 2 sinx$ being ignored is the source of the problem here.

Comment: so tan x = sin x, also - tan x = sinx, also tanx = - sinx, also -tan x = -sinx?????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align}
\tan^23x&=2\sin^23x\\
\tan^23x-2\sin^23x&=0\\
\sin^23x(\frac1{\cos^23x}-2)&=0\\
\sin^23x(\sec^23x-2)&=0
\end{align}

So we have either
\begin{align}
\sin^23x&=0\\
3x&=0^{\circ}, 180^{\circ}, 360^{\circ}\\
x&=0^{\circ}, 60^{\circ}, 120^{\circ}
\end{align}
or
\begin{align}
\sec^23x-2&=0\\
\sec^23x&=2\\
\sec3x&=\pm\sqrt2\\
3x&=45^{\circ}, 135^{\circ}, 225^{\circ}, 315^{\circ}\\
x&=15^{\circ}, 45^{\circ}, 75^{\circ}, 105^{\circ}
\end{align}

From the above, the only admissible solutions are $\boxed{15^{\circ}, 45^{\circ}, 60^{\circ}, 75^{\circ}}$.

The sum of these angles is $\boxed{195^{\circ}}$.

Comment: 75º should be included

Comment: Oops, my mistake.

Comment: The question asks for the sum, so perhaps you should include that in your answer.

Comment: basically, 135 is true, because sin 45 = cos 45? also, cos 225 = -$1/\sqrt2$?

Comment: Yes; whenever you take the square root, remember to apply the plus or minus square root.

Comment: so tan x = sin x, also - tan x = sinx, also tanx = - sinx, also -tan x = -sinx?????

Comment: Specifically, since $\sin x$ is the numerator of $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$, $\tan x=0$ requires $\sin x=0$.

Comment: @Lifeforbetter the $\pm$ is two seperate cases, both for which the thing is valid.

Comment: If $\sec^23x=2,$ $$\cos2(3x)=2(1/2)^2-1=?$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a plot that should help:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do some trigonometry and find the general solution first:
$$\tan^23x=2\sin^23x=\frac{2\tan^23x}{1+\tan^23x}\iff\tan^23x(1+\tan^23x)=2\tan^23x$$
So,

- either $\tan3x=0\iff 3x\equiv 0\mod180\iff x\equiv 0\mod 60$;
- or $\tan^23x=1\iff\tan 3x=\pm 1\iff 3x\equiv \pm45\mod 180\iff x\equiv\pm 15\mod 60$.

Then select the values in $\bigl[0,90]$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\cos6x=a,$

Using $\cos2y=1-2\sin^2y=\dfrac{1-\tan^2y}{1+\tan^2y}$

$$\dfrac{1-a}{1+a}=1-a$$

$$\implies a(a-1)=0$$

If $\cos6x=0,6x=(2n+1)90^\circ$ where $n$ is an integer

If $\cos6x=1,6x=360^\circ m$